# Which \documentclass is best to use in MWEs?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

When providing an MWE for questions, I usually use `\documentclass{article}`.  Might there be a more "minimal" class or template which would be better to use?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23175/if-you-know-errors-occurred-in-article-minimal-which-one-will-you-use-for-the

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generally, no.  The `minimal` document class is simply too minimal, and shouldn't be used.  Of course if your question involves chapters you would need to use a class like `report` or `book` that support chapters.  So `article` is an excellent choice for almost all minimal examples.

Comment: ...but add a `\pagestyle{plain}` to simplify cropping.

Comment: For information why `minimal` shouldn't be used, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Answer (score 23):

The best one to use, in my opinion, is the one that the person asking the question is actually using.  For example, if you are using `memoir`, it may interact with some other packages in a different way than `book` or `article` and the answer provided using `article` may not be working for `memoir`.  A MWE should be obtained by removing as much content from the actual work-in-progress file as possible while demonstrating the problem to be solved.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly a reason why one *should* use article in the MWE, to pinpoint the problems arising by using another class. If the problem vanishes by using article, ask a question that highlights that the bug especially appears with the other class.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, `standalone` is a good choice **if** the example consists of a separate formula or picture to be typeset. This simplifies including the result into the answer, because then the PDF contains only the relevant parts and does not need to be cropped anymore.

Comment: I think that `standalone` should be avoided for this purpose, especially for answers, since it introduces a class that is not likely to be helpful to the questioner and may in fact confuse them, depending on their knowledge.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I didn't know how to typeset material tightly until I learned about the `standalone` package by accident. So I'd rather question that it is "not likely to be helpful". I agree about the confusion, but the most natural thing in this forum would be to ask a question and/or to link to this question if confusion arises.

Comment: At least on Windows, I use Irfanview for tightly cropping from the TeXworks viewer. Alt-PrintScreen to capture the viewer window, switch to Irfanview, Ctrl-V to paste the image, drag a box around the content, Ctrl-Y to crop to the box, Ctrl-Shift-Y to autocrop the new image, save, and post.